# Is there a way to show a gif inside a SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, surfaceview, gif

I created a surfaceVeiw with a custom Background and a little figure. So far so good. Is there a posibility to show a Explosion (not as one picture but as a little video) when the figure collides with objects?

I already created these objects so the only thing I need to know is, how I can implement a method to show such explosion.

Do you need some code to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use glide libray for showing gif in android

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .asGif()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_gif)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Bound mismatch: The generic method into(Y) of type GenericRequestBuilder<ModelType,DataType,ResourceType,TranscodeType> is not applicable for the arguments (Background). The inferred type Background is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <Y extends Target<GifDrawable>>

Comment: Have you add a dependency on glide module

Comment: well, I don't know what imageUrl is supposed to mean and I have no imageView in my surfacView :/

Comment: image url is your imageview in which you want to laod gif image, Add a dependency on glide library add this line in  your gradle file

Comment: 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'

Comment: I have no gradle, i imported glide via .jar into libs on eclipse

Comment: Are you using eclipse or Android Studio